# Python Object Oriented Tkinter - Calling Function Error

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a login button on the Login frame, I want the login button to only take me to the AdminHome frame if "valid" is entered in the username entry. I can't get the show_frame() function to run in the validate() function (located in the Login Class).

I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'show_frame' is not defined
```

How would I overcome this error and get it to run?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Login, AdminHome):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Login(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):        
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")        

        pagename = tk.Label(innerFrame, text = "iDea Academy Progress Tracker Login")
        pagename.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")


        username = tk.Label(innerFrame, text="Username: ")
        username.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        self.user = ttk.Entry(innerFrame, text ="", width=45)
        self.user.grid(row=1, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="w")


        password = tk.Label(innerFrame, text="Password: ")
        password.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        self.passentry = ttk.Entry(innerFrame, text ="", width=45, show="*")
        self.passentry.grid(row=2, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="W")


        login = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "Login", command = self.validate)
        login.grid(row=3, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")

    def validate(self):
        if self.user.get()=="valid":
            show_frame(AdminHome)

class AdminHome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        fetch = ttk.Button(self, text = "Fetch Data", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        fetch.grid(row=2, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")



app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: go back to the original code you copied and notice how it calls `show_frame`

Comment: @BryanOakley 'show_frame' in my old code is called using 'lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome)' but that doesnt work when used in the 'validate()' function.

Comment: So ask yourself: what is `controller` and why is it significant? You shouldn't be just copying code and hoping to make it work, you need to first _understand_ the code before trying to change it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I dont actually know what the controller does, mind pointing me to a resource I can use to learn?

Comment: everything the controller does is defined right in that file. The controller is an instance of `Program`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would do it: I would get rid of the `validate` method in your login frame, and seperately define a function for validation. This would look like this:

```
def validate(user):
    global app
    print(user)
    if user=="valid":
        app.show_frame(AdminHome)
```

Then, in your command for the login button, simply change it to be: `lambda: validate(self.user.get())`.